# search by specific key of nested object/array javascript

Tags: javascript, object, search, nested

I would like to search by specific key on nested array/ object on javascript and need to return all hierarchy structure, include it's parent until root parent and also it's child.
Here is the sample json:

```
        let array = [
        { 
          "no": "1",
          "name": "abc",
          "child" : [
              { 
                  "no": "1.1",
                  "name": "def",
                  "child" : [
                      {
                          "no": "1.1.1",
                          "name": "Foo"
                      },
                      {
                          "no": "1.1.2",
                          "name": "jkl"
                      }
                      ] 
              },
              { 
                  "no": "1.2",
                  "name": "Foo",
                  "child" : [
                      {
                          "no": "1.2.1",
                          "name": "Foo"
                      },
                      {
                          "no": "1.2.2",
                          "name": "aaaaaaa"
                      }
                      ] 
              }
          ]
          },
       { 
          "no": "2",
          "name": "abc2",
          "child" : [
              { 
                  "no": "2.1",
                  "name": "Foo",
                  "child" : [
                      {
                          "no": "1.1.1",
                          "name": "ghi"
                      },
                      {
                          "no": "1.1.2",
                          "name": "jkl"
                      }
                      ] 
              },
              { 
                  "no": "2.2",
                  "name": "ghssssi",
                  "child" : [
                      {
                          "no": "2.2.1",
                          "name": "ghssssi"
                      },    
                      {
                          "no": "2.2.2",
                          "name": "asass"
                      }
                      ] 
              }
          ]
      }
    ];
```

And when we want to search by key ='Foo', the result would be something like this:

```
        array_result = [
      { 
          "no": "1",
          "name": "abc",
          "child" : [
              { 
                  "no": "1.1",
                  "name": "def",
                  "child" : [
                      {
                          "no": "1.1.1",
                          "name": "Foo"
                      }
                      ] 
              },
              { 
                  "no": "1.2",
                  "name": "Foo",
                  "child" : [
                      {
                          "no": "1.2.1",
                          "name": "Foo"
                      }
                      ] 
              }
          ]
      },
       { 
          "no": "2",
          "name": "abc2",
          "child" : [
              { 
                  "no": "2.1",
                  "name": "Foo",
                  "child" : [
                      {
                          "no": "1.1.1",
                          "name": "ghi"
                      },
                      {
                          "no": "1.1.2",
                          "name": "jkl"
                      }
                      ] 
              }
          ]
      }
    ];
```

I'm sure it will need recursive function. Anyone got idea?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Show us your code so someone can point out the problem. This is not the place to get complete code answers.

Comment: would you like to get a copy of the original data without mutating the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a copy from the original array and filter the array, if it has the wanted value or the children have the value.

```js
var array = [{ no: "1", name: "abc", children: [{ no: "1.1", name: "def", children: [{ no: "1.1.1", name: "Foo" }, { no: "1.1.2", name: "jkl" }] }, { no: "1.2", name: "Foo", children: [{ no: "1.2.1", name: "Foo" }, { no: "1.2.2", name: "aaaaaaa" }] }] }, { no: "2", name: "abc2", children: [{ no: "2.1", name: "Foo", children: [{ no: "1.1.1", name: "ghi" }, { no: "1.1.2", name: "jkl" }] }, { no: "2.2", name: "ghssssi", children: [{ no: "2.2.1", name: "ghssssi" }, { no: "2.2.2", name: "asass" }] }] }],
    find = 'Foo',
    result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)).filter(function search(a) {
        var children;
        if (a.name === find) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!Array.isArray(a.children)) {
            return false;
        }
        children = a.children.filter(search);
        if (children.length) {
            a.children = children;
            return true;
        }
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks @nina, it helped me a lot. I've modified the code based on my need.